# List loses shape when appending a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using PIL to load images and then transform them to NumPy arrays. Then I've to create a new image based on a list of images, so I append all theearrays to a list and then transform the list back to an array, so the shape for the list of images has 4 dimensions (n_images, height, width, rgb_channels). I'm using this code:

```
def gallery(array, ncols=4):

    nindex, height, width, intensity = array.shape
    nrows = nindex // ncols
    # want result.shape = (height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity)

    result = (array.reshape(nrows, ncols, height, width, intensity)
              .swapaxes(1,2)
              .reshape(height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity))
    return result

def make_array(dim_x):
        for i in range(dim_x):
           print('series',i) 
           series = []
           for j in range(TIME_STEP-1):
              print('photo',j)
              aux = np.asarray(Image.open(dirpath+'/images/pre_images /series_{0}_Xquakemap_{1}.jpg'.format(i,j)).convert('RGB'))
              print(np.shape(aux))
              series.append(aux)
              print(np.shape(series))

        im = Image.fromarray(gallery(np.array(series)))
        im.save(dirpath+'/images/gallery/series_{0}_Xquakemap.jpg'.format(i))
        im_shape = (im.size)

make_array(n_photos)
# n_photos is the total of photos in the dirpath
```

The problem is when the append on the `series` list happened, the shape of the image (the NumPy array added) gets lost. So when trying to reshape the array in the function `gallery` it causes a problem. A snippet of the output for the code above is this one:

```
...

series 2
photo 0
(585, 619, 3)
(1, 585, 619, 3)
photo 1
(587, 621, 3)
(2,)
photo 2
(587, 621, 3)
(3,)
photo 3
(587, 621, 3)
(4,)
...
```

As you can see, when appending the second photo the list loses a dimension. This is weird because the code works the first two iterations, which use fairly the same images. I tried using `np.stack()` but the error prevails.

I also find this [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8766) on Github but I think it doesn't apply to this case even if the behavior is similar.

Working on Ubuntu 18, Python 3.7.3 and Numpy 1.16.2.

**edit:** added what @kwinkunks asked

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do. Your function doesn't return anything and you never call it. Maybe you can make a complete, runnable example? (E.g. with random image-like data.) Questions I have: why are you converting the arrays into lists? What does the function `gallery()` do? Do all the images in a series have the same shape?

Comment: I edited the questions to add what you asked. To answer your questions: 1. I was doing that because the issue I linked said it was a workaround, but the problem keeps showing with or without that. 2. ```gallery``` creates a grid with the list of images 3. yes, all the images have the same shape. In the output, the first tuple shows the image shape ```print(np.shape(aux))``` the second one the series shape ```print(np.shape(series))```

Comment: Photo 0 has a different shape than the others.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear. You're making a new `series` for every step in `range(dim_x)`, so you're only going to get the last one you make; maybe you want to do the image-forming steps inside that outer loop? It would help to see examples of the input and the expected output. And it would really help to have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). FWIW, my advice is to not manage everything in a big ndarray, swapping axes and changing shapes, etc, and instead to manage lists of images (say). "Keep it simple," in other words.

Comment: I had a go at answering, based on deciding that `series = []` is in the wrong place. I hope it's at least going in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the second function, I think you need to move `series = []` to before the outer loop.**

Here's my reproduction of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

TIME_STEP = 3

def gallery(array, ncols=4):
    """Stitch images together."""
    nindex, height, width, intensity = array.shape
    nrows = nindex // ncols
    result = array.reshape(nrows, ncols, height, width, intensity)
    result = result.swapaxes(1,2)
    result = result.reshape(height*nrows, width*ncols, intensity)
    return result

def make_array(dim_x):
    """Make an image from a list of arrays."""
    series = []  # <<<<<<<<<<< This is the line you need to check.
    for i in range(dim_x):
        for j in range(TIME_STEP - 1):
            aux = np.ones((100, 100, 3)) * np.random.randint(0, 256, 3)
            series.append(aux.astype(np.uint8))

    im = Image.fromarray(gallery(np.array(series)))

    return im

make_array(4)
```

This results in:

[image: The output: lots of squares]

Comment: That was it! The other problem I had was one of the images was changed in size by other function. Thanks